# How can I reduce spaces between rows in css/html?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, pug

Hi I am trying to achieve the following result (with flex-box if it matters) so that my text rows are with very little spacing between them:

**Desired Result:**

[image: required result in blue square]

**My best effort so far:**

[image: my result]

Using **PUG**

```
.blackheader {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  line-height: 0px;
}

.blueblackheader {
  height: 60px;
  width: 62.5px;
  overflox-x: auto;
  background-color: #ededed;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 1px 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #034ea2;
  font-family: prored-bold;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}

.blackheader .blueblackheader p The br p Weather br p Channel
```

Comment: Show the html code.

Comment: adjust line-height here `.blueblackheader`